# Do you know of any good UML sample?

Tags: uml

I need some sample UML diagrams for some project of medium complexity. Do you know of anywhere where I can find some? I don't need them for learning UML, but rather to test my application that I work on and that should be able to process UML diagrams.

It would suffice to have Class diagram, Package diagram and Component diagram, but those should all model the same system and should be consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an [Oracle paper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/readme-084760.html) which contains the design of a Web Store application. This paper has all kinds of UML diagrams that one may want - Class, Component, Sequence, Data Model etc. It may not have package diagrams but, those are trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this site, they have nice examples in the product tutorials:

[Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should be more concrete about what format you need... Also, it might be interesting to try out some reverse engineering from existing code.